# How to access S3 data in Fiori?

Tags: sapui5

I would like to access the data from S3 in Fiori. If that possible, what are the best practices to learn sap UI5 Fiori

Comment: Is the term S3 referring to Amazon S3?
The official SAPUI5 documentation already mentioned in the answer is a very good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best place to learn is the [SAPUI5 documentation](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#/topic/8b49fc198bf04b2d9800fc37fecbb218).

There are a lot of Tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the SAPUI5, Fiori community!

There are several places to begin learning SAPUI5 and Fiori.

In addition to the [documentation](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#/topic/8b49fc198bf04b2d9800fc37fecbb218) mentioned by IBN, you can consider the following:

- [Complete tutorials and exercises with explanation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/8b49fc198bf04b2d9800fc37fecbb218)
- [Free, self-paced Open SAP Course to begin your learning](https://open.sap.com/courses/ui51/items/13DbekJ5zqd9c2IOUxPKUg)
- [SAPUI5 Youtube channel for understanding essential concepts](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCw4_GP-dk6yTzgliUMF95ew/videos)

In Addition, there are several blogs and ample documentation across the internet. Let me know if this helps. Happy learning!